# the code show bad input and index out of range on the lines, how can i fix it

Tags: python, python-3.x

what‘s the problem with my code and how can I fix it.

The problems are in lines:

world[r].append(element)

world = createWorld()

world = createWorld()

Now I show all of the code, but it seems too long need more text to make it available to post, so ignore this part.so ignore this part.so ignore this part.so ignore this part.so ignore this part.so ignore this part.so ignore this part.so ignore this part.so ignore this part.so ignore this part.so ignore this part.

This was the error given:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

There are more details in the code below, appreciate it if you can help:)

```
import random

SIZE = 4
EMPTY = " "
PERSON = "P"
PET = "T"
POOP = "O"
ERROR = "!"
CLEANED = "."
MAX_RANDOM = 10


def clean(world, endRow, endColumn):
    print("Scooping the poop")

    for r in range(SIZE):
        for c in range(SIZE):
             if world[r][c] == POOP:
                 world[r][c] = CLEANED

def count(world, endRow, endColumn):
    print("Counting number of occurances of a character")
    number = 0
    element = input("Enter character: ")

    for r in range(SIZE):
        for c in range(SIZE):
            if world[r][c] == element:
                number += 1

    return(element, number)


def createElement():
    tempNum = random.randrange(MAX_RANDOM)+1

    if ((tempNum >= 1) and (tempNum <= 5)):
        tempElement = EMPTY

    elif ((tempNum >= 6) and (tempNum <= 7)):
        tempElement = PERSON

    elif (tempNum == 8):
        tempElement = PET

    elif ((tempNum >= 9) and (tempNum <= 10)):
        tempElement = POOP

    else:
        tempElement = ERROR

    return(tempElement)


def createWorld():
    world = [] 
    r = 0


    while (r < SIZE):
        world.append([]) 
        c = 0
        while (c < SIZE):
            element = createElement()
            world[r].append(element)
            c = c + 1
            r = r + 1
        return(world)

def display(world):
    print("OUR WORLD")
    print("========")
    r = 0
    while (r < SIZE):
        c = 0
        while (c < SIZE):
            print(world[r][c], end="")
            c = c + 1
        print()
        r = r + 1
    print("========\n")


def getEndPoint():
    endRow = int(input("Enter the row: "))
    while not 0 <= endRow <= 3:
        print("Invalid input. Row value should be in range 0-3")
        endRow = int(input("Enter the row: "))
    endColumn = int(input("Enter the column: "))
    while not 0 <= endColumn <= 3:
        print("Invalid input. Column value should be in range 0-3")
        endColumn = int(input("Enter the column: "))
  
    return (endRow, endColumn)
  
def start():
    
    world = createWorld()
    display(world)
    endRow, endColumn = getEndPoint()
    element, number = count(world, endRow, endColumn)
    print("# occurances of %s=%d" % (element, number))
    clean(world, endRow, endColumn)
    display(world)
    
start()
```

Comment: Please add more context to your code, there seems to be many missing key competments in order for one to help solve your problem.

Comment: Your code has some missing items. It will be better to add more code.

Comment: All code should be showed properly now, please check thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the r value in the outer loop, currently it is being updated in the inner loop.

```
def createWorld():
    world = []
    r = 0

    while (r < SIZE):
        world.append([])
        c = 0
        while (c < SIZE):
            element = createElement()
            world[r].append(element)
            c = c + 1
        r = r + 1
    return (world)
```